# Martix Logical comparison

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, hsv

In matlab i have hue plane in a matrix and the most common colors(top 5% of the hues) in an  another matrix(L). I want to create a binary image where only rare colors are present.

Hue plane is 253X320 matrix the L matrix is 6X1.

`for l = 1 : size(HuePlane,1)
    for m = 1 : size(HuePlane,2)
        for n = 1:size(L,1)
            if L(n,1) == HuePlane(l,m)
                H(l,m) = 0;
            else

                H(l,m) = 1;
            end
        end
    end
end`

This results in a matrix of only 1s.

Comment: take a look at `ismember`, it exactly implements what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel mentioned, using `ismember` is the best solution and you should use it:

```
H = ~ismember(HuePlane, L)
```

However I thought I'd show you where you've gone wrong in your loop solution. Basically you're always comparing each colour in `HuePlane` to EVERY element of `L` sequentially which means you only store the result of the LAST comparison. In otherwords you are only checking against `L(end)`. This is what I think you were trying to do:

```
H = ones(size(HuePlane)); %// This pre-allocation is essential in Matlab! Your code will be terribly inefficient if you don't do it.
for l = 1 : size(HuePlane,1)
    for m = 1 : size(HuePlane,2)
        for n = 1:size(L,1)
            if L(n,1) == HuePlane(l,m)
                H(l,m) = 0;
                break; %// No point checking against the rest of L once we've found a match!
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But this is a very inefficient way to go.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm trying to follow your original idea)

```
h = 0*H;
for ii = 1:length(L)
    hh = H==L(ii);
    h = max(hh,h);
end
```